# Redirect with POST data from a django view

Tags: django, redirect, post, request

I have a form that goes to one of my django views. In that view, I want to do some verifications and generate other new data. Then, I have to redirect to a external web which asks me the data I have verified and have created in my view in a POST way.

Is this possible? How can I reach that behaviour?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try to write some code to acomplish this?

Comment: Are you working with Some webservice in that external website.If yes,Then Django rest framework app can be your answer.

Comment: I have tried to do it setting the params like 'request.POST['param'] = value', and the redirect to the web, but request.POST is unmutable... so the external web didn't receive the data. The external web is waiting for a form with these post params. And I have to redirect to that page, so I cannot use the REST framework.